# Formula to calculate the distance between points within a group

Tags: formula

In my problem, there are n-number of groups. Each group contains k-number of points.
The number of nodes can vary in groups. I have to select the group whose points are closely located (closely located in terms of distance).
For this purpose, first I have to calculate the closeness of points within a group (for each group I have to calculate the closeness metric).
I need guidance regarding the formula to calculate the distance between nodes within the cluster.
Please guide me which formula suits this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your points have some x y coords and depend on your structure
you can use

1)Manhattan distance: (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)

2)shortest path distance (straight line):   square root of ((x2 -x1)^2 + (y2 -y1)^2)

edit: you could make your groups as graph and use some algorithm for shortest path (something like dijkstra shortest path), and get the nearest from the starting location, and then maybe calculate what is the distance